# fibonacci time complexity with memoization and without it

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, fibonacci, memoization

I have 2 versions of the fibonacci function - memoized and not memoized. Can someone explain why non-memoized version is much faster on small values(i have tested in chrome)? Would be perfect if someone can provide links to the according v8 documentation section(s).

https://jsfiddle.net/dmni3865/qmf29dnp/3/

results on my pc:
memoized: fib(5) - 0.5, fib(10) - 0.3
not memoized: fib(5) - 0.1, fib(10) - 0.1

```js
const memo = [];
memo[0] = 0;
memo[1] = 1;

function fibonacciWithMemo(n) {
  if(memo[n] != undefined){    
    return memo[n];
  }
  memo[n] = fibonacciWithMemo(n-2) + fibonacciWithMemo(n-1);  
  return memo[n];
}

function fibonacci(n) {
    if (n < 2) {
    return n;
  } else {
    return fibonacci(n-2) + fibonacci(n-1);
  }
}

let start = performance.now();
console.log(fibonacciWithMemo(5), memo)
console.log('executed: '+(performance.now() - start));
start = performance.now();
console.log(fibonacciWithMemo(10), memo)
console.log('executed: '+(performance.now() - start));
start = performance.now();
console.log(fibonacci(5))
console.log('executed: '+(performance.now() - start));
start = performance.now();
console.log(fibonacci(10))
console.log('executed: '+(performance.now() - start));
```

Comment: A few calls of an extremely cheap function will tell you next to nothing about that function's speed relative to another

Comment: Your timing code is flawed - you want to do a lot of repetitions and take the average (at the minimum).